# Can we format SD card present in nikon dslr from computer connected over USB cable

Tags: usb, sd-card, camera

I have to format the SD card present in dslr (Nikon) from desktop (preferably ubuntu) connected over usb cable.

I am using ubuntu desktop with libgphoto2 camera library to control my dslr. I can capture image, record video, copy images from camera to computer, delete images etc.. I have also checked nikon sdk but couldn't find relevant help.

I want to know first whether formatting SD card is possible or not. If yes, how can we achieve so.

Comment: It is advisable to format cards from the camera itself if you are willing to use it on camera only.

Comment: It depends if the camera provides the storage as normal storage/bulk device (=> you can format just like you would format any other storage) or via some protocol (e.g. MTP) (=> you cannot format). What is your goal? Why won't you just use the camera's format option? You could also just use any SD Card reader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Basically i am trying to automate camera test cases, there i need to automate a usecase which formats SD card.

Comment: @pLumo, actually i am trying to simulate the same behavior i.e formatting SD card from camera, i need to format from desktop over usb cable.

Comment: @pLumo if suppose i mount dslr as disk using gphotofs in ubuntu and then try to format using mkfs will this be same as formatting from camera itself ? How can we check what type of storage our camera provides like normal/bulk. what i know is that it is connected over PTP right now.

Comment: camera is connected over "USB PTP Class Camera". I have tried mounting using gphotofs but don't know how to format as same is not reflecting in fdisk.